# Error in drupal-commons installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-commons, acquia

i´ve got drupal 7 installed on my pc running on localhost from Acquia Dev stack. Now i tried to installed Drupal-Commonns, but i got this error when the Install Profile stage is running:

An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows.
Path:
.......

```
siteChoose site color paletteEnter Homepage welcome textCreate the first groupFinished       
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dc.watchdog' doesn't exist
```

what might it be?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **`Database logging`** module.
This module will create **`watchdog`** table.

After that this error will go away.
Hope this will help. :)